# How to move plot space programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm using Core Plot Framework in my app and i have one question:

is there a way to move a plot space programatically without user interaction?

Right now im trying to use this method but i cannot move the plot space.

```
-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)displacement{
return displacement;
```

}

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That's a delegate method that is called in response to user interaction with the plot space.

You can change the `xRange` and/or `yRange` of the plot space at any time. Just be sure to make the changes from the main application thread. See the Mac version of *CPTTestApp* to see an example of using sliders to change the plot ranges and the "Real Time Plot" in the *Plot Gallery* app for an example using a timer.